# I can't get SSE register arithmetic to work

Tags: math, assembly, nasm, sse, cpu-registers

I'll try to keep the code concise. This is a snippet that asks a user to input 2 values. Putting them in xmm0 and xmm1. Adds them together, and stores them back into xmm0. The output is always just double xmm1 though.

i.e. User inputs 5 and 7, it then outputs 14. When it should output 12.

```
;Prompt user
call scanf
```

==========Moving data into register==================

```
pop     r14
push    r14
movsd   xmm0, [rsp]    ;moves inputed number into SSE register xmm0
pop     r14



;Prompt user again
call scanf
```

==========Moving more data into register==================

```
pop     r15
push    r15
movsd   xmm1, [rsp]    ;moves inputed number into SSE register xmm1
pop     r15
```

=========Math=========

```
addsd    xmm0, xmm1    ;xmm0 = xmm0 + xmm1
```

=====Print to screen=====

```
mov         rdi, floatformat            
mov qword   rax, 1                                           
call        printf
```

Comment: Show the _entire_ assembly code of the function, please. If you perform `call` then you might need to save/restore some register contents around that (amongst others, _all_ SSE registers you use).

Comment: And the move from xmm0 to whatever register printf consumes is not clear. Same with that calling scanf twice yields results in different registers.

Comment: You should use a debugger to check for multiple things, such as: are the values being added even the values the user entered, is the output even the actual calculated sum, etc.